# restrict queries excution based on input parameter in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

My question is I had created one procedure with the input of 6 parameters but I need to restrict the queries execution based on the input parameter. I don't want to execute all queries simultaneously in the procedure while passing all 6 parameters. For example, I will give all 6 parameters while calling the procedure. I need only 1 parameter passed query data because it will be passed to only one query in that procedure.So, can anyone sort out this issue.

Comment: @Pkumar said "will you please post your code here to know which parameter you want to execute." and I agree. But I'll also add that you need to post your sample data and expected result as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.